# somthing went wrong! error code: 1 message: undefined (Media plugin)

Tags: cordova, angular, audio, ionic2

i have an audio(.mp3) file in my assets folder and on clicking a button i am trying to play the audio using [this plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/mediaplugin/)

in my .ts file

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform:Platform) {
    // const onStatusUpdate = (status) => console.log(status);

    // const file = new MediaPlugin('assets/audio/demo.mp3', onStatusUpdate);
  }

  playAudio(){
   // Create a MediaPlugin instance.  Expects path to file or url as argument
  // We can optionally pass a second argument to track the status of the media
  this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
    const onStatusUpdate = (status) => console.log(status);

    const file = new MediaPlugin('assets/audio/demo.mp3', onStatusUpdate);

    // Catch the Success & Error Output
    // Platform Quirks
    // iOS calls success on completion of playback only
    // Android calls success on completion of playback AND on release()

    file.init.then(() => {
      console.log('Playback Finished');
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('somthing went wrong! error code: ' + err.code + ' message: ' + err.message);
    });

    // play the file
    file.play();
  });
  }
}
```

Errors i got on chrom://inspect

> somthing went wrong! error code: 1 message: undefined

Comment: hello.. what is the error ?:)

Comment: `error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomePage class HomePage - inline template:14:2 caused by: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`  this error i am getting in ionic serve

Comment: Also any plugn call should be within `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`

Comment: after `ionic run android` in my chrome inspect i got this `somthing went wrong! error code: 1 message: undefined` @suraj

Comment: put the entire thing within platform.. cordova plugins are loaded once the platform is ready

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137199/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj).